# "You can now switch to a Let’s Encrypt certificate." - should I?

Tags: security, certificates, letsencrypt, devuan, jitsi-meet

I recently apt-get dist-upgraded my Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera machine. after upgrading the package `jitsi-meet-web-config` to version 1.0.5818-1, I get a message saying:

```
You can now switch to a Let’s Encrypt certificate. To do so, execute:
/usr/share/jitsi-meet/scripts/install-letsencrypt-cert.sh
```

My questions:

1. What is Jitsi using before that?
2. Why couldn't I switch before?
3. Should I switch now?

Comment: you're running a jitsi server?

Comment: @pLumo: Not intentionally...

Comment: is your setup directly exposed to outside traffic? letsencrypt seems to have been an options since 2017 - before that, there was no TLS certificate used, or perhaps a self signed one?

Comment: @Bravo: It's on a machine behind a firewall, and there's no rule to forward traffic to a jitsi-related port.

Comment: What's wrong with running a jitsi server?

Comment: then @einpoklum - 1. nothing, 2. that's a mystery, 3. no need

Comment: @Bravo: Then maybe I should just uninstall some package responsible for running the server?